# need to lay out the Buttons and image when rotate the device

Tags: ios, layout

i need to relayout some buttons and image when the user rotate the device. Could you please help me to do it or give me an example of code to do this? i need to move the buttons as the images below:

potrait like this: https://flic.kr/p/oQ2zzA
and landscape like this: https://flic.kr/p/ozyMGJ

Comment: What have you tried or researched already? It helps get an answer if you have can show something more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend reading up on Auto-Layout where adding constraints to each object on your storyboard/xib will instruct where they would be placed in relation to each other etc when the device is rotated.

Here is a link to a auto-layout tutorial

[beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

Once the constraints have been set, there are many advanced ways to use code to animate the constraints themselves, which can be programatically changed and so on.

In the meantime though, I hope this helps as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks Jeely, I will follow your link.